# when we resize the window contents in the window should be modified

Tags: c#, winforms

code for displaying hex data into a richtext box, so now  the problem is that when i resize the window the data in richtextbox should 
be changed.

```
            int length = (int)fileInfo.Length;
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileInfo.Name, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, length);


            string bb = "";
            int i = 0;
            //int numBytesToRead = buffer.Length; ;
            while (i < buffer.Length)
            {
                if ((i % 16) == 0)
                {
                    bb = bb + "\n";
                    bb = bb + i.ToString("X8");
                    bb = bb + "\t";
                }
                else if ((i % 4) == 0)
                {
                    bb = bb + "\t";
                }
                bb = bb + buffer[i].ToString("X2"); // modified on 30june2014
               // if ((i % 4) == 0)
               // {
               //    
               // }
                i = i + 1;
            }
            richTextBox2.Text = bb;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Form's size changed event as follows:

```
private void Form1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     richTextBox2.Text=bb;//or what you want
}
```

Have a look at this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.sizechanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

Since you are lazy to search how to do this:

Go to your form's properties window, and click on the events icon as below

[image: Form Properties]

And then double click on the SizeChanged. Then you can code the method.

Comment: actually the requirement is resizing will be done manually, so when i or client resize the form the contents should be changed but aligned in a good way

Comment: You wrote to the question "when i resize the window the data in richtextbox should be changed". So what do you mean it will be done manually?

Comment: yes, actually the richtextbox is here displaying hex data so when resizing is done the data should be aligned systematically

Comment: What is the relation between hex data and window size? I really don't have any clue about what you ask for.

Comment: Actually now, I am displaying the hexdata in 16,32,48,64,80..... pattern so when I resize the form then it should be like 8,16,24,32.... like this pattern

Comment: Ok then, you have to know when the window is resized, right? You can know that by using this SizeChanged event. When the window size changed that event will be triggered and you can do what ever you want with your numbers.

Comment: Ok Oguz Sezer, thanks for helping, now i will try this.

Comment: @ Oguz Sezer, there is no any event as Form_SizeChanged within the event tab

Comment: @rocky just double click on the blank area. it will generate the name for you.

Comment: Can you help me how to write the code or logic  @ Oguz Sezer

Comment: please help me dude I am a Fresher please